# TYPO3 - Modifying Introduction Package CSS?

Tags: css, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a TYPO3 9.3.0 installation with the introduction and bootstrap packages and I am unable to find any location of the styling instructions. I mainly just want to adjust the footer content and the header logo size and maybe some more along the way but I have no idea where to look to change it. The documentation seems to be all over the place and outdated too. I did a search in the server for any .css files and the search returned negative so I am really at a loss.

Answer (score 2):

The styles, layouts and overall configuration originate from `EXT:bootstrap_package` (the Bootstrap extension). You find the layout of the footer (3 columns) in file `Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Structure/Footer.html` for example. However, you should refrain from editing files *inside* extensions directly in order to keep the update funtionality (a re-install or update of the extension would overwrite your changes).

The content of the footer can be adjusted easily by editing the content elements "Related Links" (ID: 177), "Powered by" (ID: 175) and "Social Networks" (ID: 176), which are all located on the "Congratulations" page (ID: 1).

Go to: **WEB → List**, select page "Congratulations" and scroll down to table "Page Content". Edit/remove/replace the records as required.

You can also customize the theme and look'n feel by changing the configuration under:

**WEB → Template**, select page "Congratulations", select "Constant Editor" at the top. Then choose the desired "Category" (e.g. "BOOTSTRAP PACKAGE: BASIC"). There is a great number of options available, including the path to the main logo image.

Please note that some changes may require a flush of the (frontend) cache. You find this function in the TYPO3 backend at the top of the screen (the little flash icon: ⚡).

Comment: The footer edit I want to do is to remove the language selection at the bottom. I deleted the language records hoping the menu would disappear but they are still there.

I also want to adjust the layout, particularly the size of the logo. I did figure out how to change it but I want to be able to edit the website css in more detail. Where is the website style defined? Happy to be pointed to documentation that has a valid url.

Comment: Many items can be changed using the constants section of the templage. There is the bootstrap site (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/) which shows what can be set and is (mostly) also reflected in the constants section of the template.

You can there also switch off the language and other parts (eg. Meta-part)

Comment: Another source just found: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/bootstrap_package/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html